# How to remove duplicates from the list?

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a object class with these attributes:

```
@Slf4j
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class M3MachineSale {

    private Integer OPCSHC;
    private String OPITNO;
    private String OPTRDT;
    private Integer OPIVQT;

}
```

I want to remove all the duplicates. I have used `.distinct()` but it does not remove duplicates, only give me back the duplicates from the list.

```
// Remove duplicates and objects with Product = PANT L
List<M3MachineSale> updatedM3MachineSaleList = m3MachineSaleList.stream()
                .filter(m3MachineSale -> !m3MachineSale.getOPITNO().equals("PANT L"))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

What am I doing worong? I know I have some objects with same attributes, but I want to remove these from the list, not return the duplicates.

Input list:

```
M3MachineSale(OPCSHC=123, OPITNO=5562, OPTRDT=20200821, OPIVQT=1)
M3MachineSale(OPCSHC=123, OPITNO=5562, OPTRDT=20200821, OPIVQT=1)
M3MachineSale(OPCSHC=456, OPITNO=3497, OPTRDT=20200821, OPIVQT=15)
M3MachineSale(OPCSHC=789, OPITNO=6663, OPTRDT=20200821, OPIVQT=4)
M3MachineSale(OPCSHC=456, OPITNO=3497, OPTRDT=20200821, OPIVQT=15)
```

Output should be:

```
M3MachineSale(OPCSHC=123, OPITNO=5562, OPTRDT=20200821, OPIVQT=1)
M3MachineSale(OPCSHC=456, OPITNO=3497, OPTRDT=20200821, OPIVQT=15)
M3MachineSale(OPCSHC=789, OPITNO=6663, OPTRDT=20200821, OPIVQT=4)
```

I have tried do this to find duplicates:

```
    private <T> Predicate<T> distinctByKey(Function<? super T, Object> keyExtractor) {
    Map<Object, Boolean> seen = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    return t -> seen.putIfAbsent(keyExtractor.apply(t), Boolean.FALSE) == null;
}
```

And it returned a list that i have 605 duplicates.
Example from [Baekdung](https://www.baeldung.com/java-streams-distinct-by)

Any idea how I can do it? Thank for the help!

Comment: update your post with sample input and expected output

Comment: convert to a set instead of a list?

Comment: Did you implement the equals and hashCode methods in M3MachineSale? Can you post the code for them

Comment: Stream has a [`distinct()` operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#distinct--). That will require equals and hashcode (lombok's `@EqualsAndHashCode`)

Comment: Why you dont use SET list?

Comment: I have tried with implement `@EqualsAndHashCode` and `distinct()`. Not working and either with list of Set.

Comment: `distinct()` working for me

Answer (score 1):

In your christmas tree of lombok annotations, you forgot `@EqualsAndHashCode` which makes de-duplication not possible.

I suggest you reduce your batch down to just `@Data @Slf4j @NoArgsConstructor @AllArgsConstructor` which does all that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach. I was able to remove duplicates with distinct() before collect().

```
List<M3MachineSale> updatedM3MachineSaleList = m3MachineSaleList.stream()
    .filter(m3MachineSale  -> !m3MachineSale.getOPITNO().equals("PANT L"))
    .distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Working example here https://onlinegdb.com/BJA-h5z7P

Comment: The problem is, distinct() uses equals which hasn't been overridden.